# LWC File Upload component ignores accept setting for drag-and-drop

Tags: lightning-web-components, fileupload

There is a strange behaviour in [LWC File Upload component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-file-upload/documentation).

There are two ways how files can be uploaded through this component.

The user can:

- Select a file on your system by clicking the button to open the
  system's file browser
- Drag a file from your system into the file selector dropzone

If the user uses the first way, the `accept` format filter works well, only accepted file formats are allowed.

If the user uses the second way, however, the `accept` format doesn't have effect, and user can still upload a file which doesn't conform to the accepted file formats.

So, if we set file format to `.pdf` and `.xlsx`, the user cannot select `.xls` file in the file browser but can upload `.xls` file by using drag and drop feature.

Is there a simple UI workaround for this? Is this a platform bug? How this can be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Though i have not confirmed its a bug in my instance of the Salesforce developer org, A workaround i have used for this is:-

> You can write a validation rule on ContentVersion Object to restrict
> the file type not respected by file upload component.

1. To avoid this validation rule firing at other places in Salesforce instead of custom Lightning component, you can have a custom field on Content version object and update it from file upload component. Refer this custom field in validation rule for bypass mechanism.
2. the org admin can create a custom field on the `ContentVersion` object. The field type can be text or picklist. The API name of the custom field must end with `fileupload__c`.
3. Specify the `file-field-name` and `file-field-value` attributes in lightning-file-upload to store a value in the custom field in the ContentVersion object.

e.g

```
<lightning-file-upload
            label="Attach receipt"
            name="fileUploader"
            accept={acceptedFormats}
            record-id={myRecordId}
            file-field-name="Run_Validation_fileupload__c"
            file-field-value={runValidation}
            onuploadfinished={handleUploadFinished}
            multiple>
    </lightning-file-upload>
```

Here `Run_Validation_fileupload__c` is custom field on Content Version Object and `runValidation` is a property defined in js file and holds the value of the field to be stored.

Comment: We deliver this as a part of managed package, I should think if this might be viable to use similar approach in my case

Comment: Tried this approach, so far I had the following issue: 1. the field specified in file-field-name is not updated with the value, specified in file-field-value. 2. Extension field is blank, which is weird, since when I open later this record then FileExtension is populated

Answer (score 0):

Decided to process the `uploadFinished` custom event.

Upload.html file listing

```
<template>
    <lightning-file-upload
        label={label}
        accept={acceptedFormats}
        onuploadfinished={handleUploadFinished}>
    </lightning-file-upload>
    <template if:true={fileError}>
        <div class="slds-has-error">
            <div role="alert" class="slds-form-element__help">{fileError}</div>
        </div>
    </template>
</template>
```

Upload.js file listing

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import { deleteRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

export default class Upload extends LightningElement {
    @api label = '';
    fileError = '';

    get acceptedFormats() {
        return ['.pdf', '.xlsx'];
    }

    handleUploadFinished(event) {
        let fileNameParts = event.detail.files[0].name.split('.');
        let extension = '.' + fileNameParts[fileNameParts.length - 1].toLowerCase();
        if (!this.acceptedFormats.includes(extension)) {
            this.fileError = 'This extension ' + extension + ' is not listed as accepted format';
            deleteRecord(event.detail.files[0].documentId);
        } else {
            this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('upload', {detail: {file: event.detail.files[0]}}));
            this.fileError = '';
        }
 
    }
}
```

This solution won't require additional field creation.